# Difference between mutex.timed_lock(duration) and boost::timed_mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(mutex, duration)

Tags: c++, boost, locking, boost-thread, boost-mutex

I would like to know which is the difference between:

```
boost::timed_mutex _mutex;
if(_mutex.timed_lock(boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10))){
   exclusive code
   _mutex.unlock();
}
```

and

```
boost::timed_mutex _mutex;
boost::timed_mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(_mutex, boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10));
if(scoped_lock.owns_lock()) {
   exclusive code
}
```

I do know already that the scoped_lock makes unnecessary the call to unlock. My question refers to:

1. Why in the first case we call timed_lock as member function of a
   mutex and in the second one we construct a lock from a mutex and a
   duration.
2. Which one is more efficient?
3. The usage of boost::posix_time is okay or is recommended to use another kind,
   e.g. chrono or duration?
4. There's a better way (faster) to try to
   acquire a lock for 'x' time than the two methods above specified?

Comment: Looks to me that scoped_lock is for a timed_mutex like a shared_ptr is to a raw pointer: It will unlock the mutex as soon as it will go out of scope. While it will probably have more overhead, than a simple timed_mutex (it adds an extra management layer, although probably very thin), there are some benefits. Like if you have an exception in your exclusive code, the mutex will unlock. This won't happen with a timed_mutex only.

Comment: Not a bad answer but it barely answers one out of my four questions because I already said I knew about the unnecessary unlock, so if it's handling the unlock sure it's having a bit more overhead. I'm not trying to be mean but this answer does not clear things out for me. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer your questions:

1. as you can read in this [Document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2406.html), locks are used as RAII devices for the locked state of a mutex. That is, the locks don't own the mutexes they reference. They just own the lock on the mutex. basically what it means is that you acquire the mutex lock when you initialize it's corresponding lock  and release it when the lock object is destroyed.
   that's why in the second example you didn't have to call timed_lock from the mutex, the scoped_lock does it for you when initialized.
2. I don't know if the first example is more efficient but I know for sure that the second example (the RAII scoped_lock) is much safer, it guarantees that you won't forget to unlock the mutex and ,more important, it guarantees that other people that use and modify your code won't cause any mutex related problems.
3. as far as I know you can't construct scoped_lock (which is basically`unique_lock<timed_mutex>`) from posix_time. I personally prefer duration.
4. In my opinion constructing the lock with Duration absolute time is your best option.